# Combine logistic regression with bar graph for maturity results

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to present the results of a logistic regression analysis for the maturity schedule of a fish species. Below is my reproducible code.

```
#coded with R version R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
#Frisbee Sailing 
rm(list=ls())
library(ggplot2)
library(FSA)
#generate sample data 1 mature, 0 non mature
m<-rep(c(0,1),each=25)
tl<-seq(31,80, 1)
dat<-data.frame(m,tl)
# add some non mature individuals at random in the middle of df to
#prevent glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred error
tl<-sample(50:65, 15)
m<-rep(c(0),each=15)
dat2<-data.frame(tl,m)
#final dataset
data3<-rbind(dat,dat2)
```

ggplot can produce a logistic regression graph showing each of the data points employed, with the following code:

```
#plot logistic model
ggplot(data3, aes(x=tl, y=m)) + 
   stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial", se=FALSE)+
   geom_point()
```

I want to combine the probability of being mature at a given size, which is obtained, and plotted with the following code:

```
#plot proportion of mature 
#clump data in 5 cm size classes
l50<-lencat(~tl,data=data3,startcat=30,w=5)
#table of frequency of mature individuals by size
mat<-with(l50, table(LCat, m))
#proportion of mature
mat_prop<-as.data.frame.matrix(prop.table(mat, margin=1))
colnames(mat_prop)<-c("nm", "m")
mat_prop$tl<-as.factor(seq(30,80, 5))
# Bar plot probability mature 
ggplot(mat_prop, aes(x=tl,y=m)) +
 geom_bar(stat="bin")
```

What I've been trying to do, with no success, is to make a graph that combines both, since the axis are the same it should be straightforward, but I cant seem to make t work. I have tried:

```
ggplot(mat_prop, aes(x=tl,y=m)) +
 geom_bar(stat="bin")+
 stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial", se=FALSE)
```

but does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new so not able to add the resulting graphs to this post.

Comment: Just a little remark for next time: The package `FSA` is not on CRAN and thus it is not immediately clear, how to get it. A web search [helps](https://www.rforge.net/FSA/Installation.html), of course, but you could make it easier for people to help you, by giving the link, where one can download the package. More important is, however, that you gave an example that deserves being called reproducible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three problems with your code:

- Using `stat="bin"` in your `geom_bar()` is inconsisten with giving values for the y-axis (`y=m`). If you bin, then you count the number of x-values in an interval and use that count as y-value, so there is no need to map your data to the y-axis.
- The data for the glm-plot is in `data3`, but your combined plot only uses `mat_prop`.
- The x-axis of the two plots are acutally not quite the same. In the bar plot, you use a factor variable on the x-axis, making the axis discrete, while in the glm-plot, you use a numeric variable, which leads to a continuous x-axis.

The following code gave a graph combining your two plots:

```
mat_prop$tl<-seq(30,80, 5)
ggplot(mat_prop, aes(x=tl,y=m)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity") +
   geom_point(data=data3) +
   geom_smooth(data=data3,aes(x=tl,y=m),method="glm", family="binomial", se=FALSE)
```

I could run it after first sourcing your script to define all the variables. The three problems mentioned above are adressed as follows:

- I used `geom_bar(stat="identity")` in order not to use binning in the bar plot.
- I use the `data`-argument in `geom_point` and `geom_smooth` in order to use the correct data (`data3`) for these parts of the plot.
- I redifine `mat_prop$tl` to make it numeric. It is then consistent with the column `tl` in `data3`, which is numeric as well.

(I also added the points. If you don't want them, just remove `geom_point(data=data3)`.)

The plot looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stibu, that is exactly what I was after.

Comment: Accepted, won't allow me to upvote as I'm an new user.